# Is there any way to administer multiple Django servers at once?

Tags: django, django-admin

**Short Version**

Is there any tool that will let me use a single Django admin page to affect multiple Django installations on different servers?

**Detailed Version**

I've got a bunch of different servers, each with their own Django installation.  This works great ... except when I want to do something via the Django admin to all of the servers, in which case I have to log on to each server separately.

For instance, let's say I have a release coming and a co-worker (who's not a programmer) wants to use the admin to make a "message" record about the release for the server's users to see.  They have to log in to each server's admin individually, create the message record, then move on to the next server until they've gotten through all of them.

To get around this whenever I have a multi-server change I've been using Git; ie.:

1. I make a commit with files for the change
2. I push that commit
3. I pull that commit on all of the servers at once (using Fabric).

However, this too is sub-optimal, because we can't take advantage of the admin interface, and doing something as simple as adding a "new release coming" message requires an actual (mini-)release itself.

So, it seems to me the best way to handle this would be if there was some sort of meta-admin tool my co-worker could use to Django admin work on multiple servers at once.  Does anything like that exist?

Comment: Why are your servers not using the same datastore?

Comment: Seems like a task for the [Django sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/).

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams We're not using the same datastore for non-technical business reasons (in short, our customers require their own exclusive database).

Comment: @Paulo Scardine Thanks for the suggestion, but the sites framework provides support for running multiple sites off a single server ... which doesn't at all help the case of having multiple servers.

Comment: @machineghost: IINM, as long as all sites share the same database you should be fine with the sites framework (if they share some content that would make your life easier anyway).

Comment: @Paulo Scardine You're correct, but the whole reason we have separate servers is to have separate databases.  It looks like I'm just going to have to rely on a behind-the-scenes solution (eg. Fabric), as I guess there is no "meta-"Django admin library that a non-programmer could use.

Comment: @machineghost: Of course you may have specific needs, but if you are not going with a multi-tenant data architecture, prepare for an uphill battle. You can have multiple databases in Django, perhaps you can use a local database for site-specific data and a central database for the shared models.